# Default browser detection

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

whenever you open a browser if it's not set as default one, it will ask us to set it as default.How it is sensing this. I tried google search for the answer but did not get clear information. **So how does browsers detects if it is a default one when they start?**( I use Chrome and Firefox, they do this, ask us to set them as default, not sure about other browsers).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: hi Ahmed, I have some idea about how to detect browser type from client or server side using JavaScript or libraries. But I am want to know how a browser detects itself if it 's been set or default. I guess you would have seen, browser would ask you to set it as default as it is not default now.  So how it is doing that.